# The sum of the digits of a number without arrays

Tags: javascript, numbers, sum

given `var num = 123456` how can I find the sum of its digits (which is 21 in this case) without using arrays?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Why _without using arrays_ ?

Comment: @TylerY86 its not duplicate, the other question has no mention of Arrays. I'm certain that other people will want to know if doing this, without the use of arrays is possible.

Comment: @Rayon I am solving algorithm challenges, and i needed to know if this is possible,

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost Then why didn't you search for "sum of the digits", find the other question, see that it was done without arrays, and move on?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate even though the other question didn't include the "no arrays" requirement, because the other question's accepted (and only) answer gives two possible solutions, the first of which doesn't use arrays.

Comment: @nnnnnn ok I understand, but if someone is looking for this explicitly, then I believe my question would be of better aid to them.

Comment: @TylerY86 don't be upset because I didn't select your answer for my other questions man, you were right, but the other ones were more suitable.

Comment: Sure. And with your title other people should still be able to find your question from Google or the Stackoverflow search. If I'm outvoted and people think it should be reopened I won't try to close it again...

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost You asked other questions? Wait, do you have multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var num = 123456, sum = 0;
while ( num > 0 ) { sum += (num % 10)|0; num /= 10; }
document.write(sum);
```

Comment: An alert? How quaint.

Comment: Yeah, I can do better. Any suggestions? Less quaint?

Comment: If you use `console.log()` the result will appear right there in the snippet output window (as well as in the browser's actual dev console). By the way, "quaint" does mean "*charmingly* unusual or old-fashioned"...

Comment: Works for me in Firefox, but for some reason doesn't work in my Chrome. Think I have it turned off for frames or something.

Comment: Woops, so I guess I technically went *more quaint*... ;)

Comment: @nnnnnn Anyway, pretty sure this question shouldn't have been asked. This is just golfing.

Comment: Well, I may have dragged you off course (see what I did there?) in the comments, but obviously your answer works and I did vote for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124492/discussion-between-tylery86-and-nnnnnn).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.!

```js
console.log(sumofdigits(123456));

function sumofdigits(number) {
   var sum = 0;
   while (number > 0) {
      sum += number % 10;
      number = Math.floor(number / 10);
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Added console.log() as suggested by @nnnnnn

Comment: Your function returned 23.333333333333623.

Comment: *Nice copy with no credit there.* lol You could have at least used a different way to make it an int. Anyway, this is a common dupe of a question. Probably somebody's homework. :)

Comment: nice use of out of order declaration, it's not done often enough.